# How can I find out what number in <ul> some <li> element is? In Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, robotframework

I have a < ul > with unknown number of < li > elements. Each < li > has some text and also a button. How can I identify which < li > contains the text I'm looking for, in order to click the button in that same < li >?

```
<ul>  
  <li class="ot-queryitem row-fluid">
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--left span7">
      <span class="ot-queryitem__name">Äänikysely (Voice Activity and Participation Profile)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--center span3"></div>
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--right span2">
    <button class="ot-button ot-button--undefined pull-right ot-queryitem__button">
      <i class="icon-pencil fa ot-icon ot-icon--default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
      <span>Täytä</span>
    </button>
    <span class="ot-queryitem__logo"></span></div></li>
  <li class="ot-queryitem row-fluid">
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--left span7">
      <span class="ot-queryitem__name">Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--center span3"></div>
    <div class="ot-queryitem__info ot-queryitem__info--right span2">
    <button class="ot-button ot-button--undefined pull-right ot-queryitem__button">
      <i class="icon-pencil fa ot-icon ot-icon--default" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>
      <span>Täytä</span>
    </button>
    <span class="ot-queryitem__logo"></span></div></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `//span[text()='Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti']` will give you a [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) with the given text
2. [`/ancestor::li`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor) axis will give you the parent [`<li>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)
3. [`/descendant::button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) axis will give you the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) you're looking for
4. Putting everything together:

   ```
   //span[text()='Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti']/ancestor::li/descendant::button
   ```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following xpath.

```
xpath: //ul//li[contains(.,'Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti')]//button
```

OR

```
 xpath: //ul//li[contains(.,'Äänikysely')]//button
```

However You can pass this `Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti` or `Äänikysely` as string variable in robotframework.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To identify `li` tag which contains text you looking for as -

```
${YOUR_TEXT}        Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti

## this keyword will give first matching element
${elements}=       Get WebElement    xpath://span[contains(text(),'${YOUR_TEXT}')]/ancestor::li

### wait for element to be present on page 
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${elements}

## now click on button inside li tag found in above lines
Click Button    xpath://span[contains(text(),'${YOUR_TEXT}')]/ancestor::li//button
```

note: locators are taken from the html sample you provided

Answer (score 0):

Both the element with the text and the button are child elements under each `<li>`. You need to go up the html tree from the text and then look for a button under a sibling element

```
//div[span[contains(., 'Äänikysely')]]/following-sibling::div/button
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to count the number of `<li>` within the `<ul>`.

To click on the respective button according to the text e.g. *Äänikysely*, *Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti* etc you can use the following solution:

- To click for *Äänikysely*:

  ```
  Click Button    xpath://div[contains(@class, 'ot-queryitem__info--left')]/span[contains(.,'Äänikysely')]//following::button[@class='ot-button ot-button--undefined pull-right ot-queryitem__button']//span[text()='Täytä']
  ```
- To click for *Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti*:

  ```
  Click Button    xpath://div[contains(@class, 'ot-queryitem__info--left')]/span[contains(.,'Nikotiiniriippuvuustesti')]//following::button[@class='ot-button ot-button--undefined pull-right ot-queryitem__button']//span[text()='Täytä']
  ```

Comment: 'Button with locator xxxxx not found'